# Installing text codecs using pip

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I wrote my own text codec and I want to be able to use it like any other codec:

```
"some string".encode("my-codec-name")
```

I can achieve this by putting my codec file in the `C:\python27\Lib\encodings` directory, but manual installation is not favorable.

Is there any way to install my codec using a `setup.py`, so that it can be installed using `pip`?

(Note: I know that I can import my codec before using it, and have it register itself. I prefer to avoid this method.)